# How to increment/decrement textbox value by one with onClick

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, numberpicker

First of all, please help me figure this purely in JavaScript. No jQuery or any plugins. I'm trying to code this to work in Cordova/PhoneGap. I'm teaching myself JavaScript at the same time as I'm playing with Cordova/PhoneGap so please be gentle.

I've got a textbox with buttons on either side, right for adding 1 to the textbox value (+ on it) and left for minusing 1 from the text box (- on it). My purpose is to have the page/app load for the first time showing a 0 value in the text box. As soon as someone presses the + button, the textbox should increment from 0 to 1 and by a further 1 with every click of the +. If the app is closed and re-opened, it should remember the last number that was in the textbox before the app was closed.

It works in browser testing, it causes PhoneGap's iPhone app to no longer recognize PhoneGap gestures of resetting the app and such, pressing the +/- button increments/decrements the textbox too slowly, and it can go negative despite setting min="0". What am I doing wrong? (I know localStorage can't be done in the code snippet due to sandboxing so if you'd rather I put up a JSFiddle or something, just tell me what to do.)

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var CapsNum = localStorage.getItem("CapsNum");

  if(CapsNum == null) {
   CapsNum = "0";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("caps").value = CapsNum;
}}
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 localStorage.setItem("CapsNum", document.getElementById("caps").value);
}
function PlusCaps(){
 localStorage.setItem("CapsNum",document.getElementById("caps").value++);
}

function MinusCaps(){
 localStorage.setItem("CapsNum",document.getElementById("caps").value--);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="plus" class="button" value="+" style="margin-left:10px" onclick="MinusCaps()" />
<input type="tel" id="caps" maxlength="3" size="3" min="0" max="999" pattern="[0-9]" value="0" />
<input type="button" id="minus" class="button" value="-" style="margin-right:10px" onclick="PlusCaps()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like you are changing and persisting the value into local storage.  This won't update the value on the page.  I create a small function by modifying your example that can update the state in localstorage and it updates the value in the textbox at the same time.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //var CapsNum = localStorage.getItem("CapsNum");

  if (CapsNum == null) {
    CapsNum = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("caps").value = CapsNum;
  }
}
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  localStorage.setItem("CapsNum", document.getElementById("caps").value);
}

function PlusCaps() {
 var nextValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("caps").value) + 1;
  setNextValue(nextValue);
}

function MinusCaps() {
 var nextValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("caps").value) - 1;
  setNextValue(nextValue);
}

function setNextValue(nextValue) {
  //localStorage.setItem("CapsNum", nextValue);
  document.getElementById("caps").value = nextValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="plus" class="button" value="+" style="margin-left:10px" onclick="PlusCaps()" />
<input type="tel" id="caps" maxlength="3" size="3" min="0" max="999" pattern="[0-9]" value="0" />
<input type="button" id="minus" class="button" value="-" style="margin-right:10px" onclick="MinusCaps()" />
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I loaded your code into mine and opened Chrome's developer tool, then clicked on the plus button and got this error:

'Uncaught ReferenceError: PlusCaps is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:52)'

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I imagine that you might have missed copying the PlusCaps function.  If you run the code by clicking Run code snippet does it run?

Comment: That’s the thing. I made sure the code is in there. Your snippet ran at the time I was on a computer and tried it. (I’m on the SO phone app at the moment.)

Comment: Ok. I'm stupid. I left off an end } and that bunged it all up. I fixed that and now it's not doing anything. Just to test, I took your code and stuck it in a JSfiddle to see what would happen and got the same results. What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/HidetoK/2ktbanay/

Comment: So JavaScript in JSfiddle didn't evaluate the value of the textbox to a string.  In this fiddle I worked around that.  I will update this post as well to reflect.  https://jsfiddle.net/ugx6995h/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! How do I keep the number from going negative by clicks or typing?

Comment: I also had to comment out the localstorage lines because StackOverflow is complaining about them today even though they didn't yesterday.  They are claiming that it is a Cross Site Scripting attempt.

Comment: So you can add a check inside of the MinusCap function that checks if it is less than 0 then set the nextValue variable to 0.  As far as typing it is a bit tricker.  You need to bind an event listener to the input field to check the new value when it is updated.  The easiest way to do this is using jQuery's event listeners.  https://api.jquery.com/keypress/  When a key is pressed check the value and ensure it is valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164095/discussion-between-joseph-fehrman-and-hideto).